# Hay Alguna manera de colocar una imagen en una pagina especifica con css

Tags: css, wordpress

Hola tengo una duda es que estoy trabajando con wordpress y quiero agregar una imagen de baner a una pagina en especificio, como wordpress se repiten algunas clases no deja colocar ese baner en una sola pgaina en especifico existe algun codigo que me permita colocar ese baner segun la pagina seleccionada

Comment: Hola Jesús, bienvenido a la comunidad, te invito a que pases por el [tour] para que entiendas mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso ganes tu primera medalla. También te aconsejo pasarte por [how-to-ask] para que tus entradas reciban mejor atención

Comment: Podias utilizar un plugin para colocar un banner o un slider en la pagina que desees, te recomiendo https://wordpress.org/plugins/ml-slider/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con css es posible, para ello tendrías que verificar las clases que se generan en el body, si vas a la página que deseas e inspeccionas las clases del body veras que hay una que dice post-[ID] el ID del post, por ejemplo, si el ID es 45 diría post-45, esta es una clase única y que no se repite, puedes usarla como identificador para aplicar css personalizado.

Otra idea es usar javascript y php, usando insertBefore o appendTo y hacer echo del banner con un identificador y moverlo de posición con las funciones mencionadas antes, seria mas limpio que css.

Seria algo asi

```
function add_Banner() {
    $id_page = get_the_ID();
    if ( $id_page == 'ID del post' ) {
        echo '<div id="tu-id">contenido</div>'; ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                 jQuery("tu-id").insertBefore("lugar al que quieras moverlo");
            });
        </script>

    <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_body_open', 'add_Banner' );
```

En este caso agrega tu contenido despues del body, con insertBefore lo mueves de lugar en caso de que desees hacerlo, insertBefore lo mueve antes de un elemento, con appentTo puedes moverlo dentro de un elemento, seria algo asi

```
jQuery("tu-id").appendTo("lugar al que quieras moverlo");
```

Tomar en cuenta que solo funcionara si tu plantilla tiene el hook, `wp_body_open();` agregado si no lo tiene puedes agregarlo despues del body

Comment: lo del codigo php  en que archivo lo tengo que colocar en functions.php  en la carpeta del tema??

Comment: Asi es, en el archivo functions.php de tu tema o algun plugin de snippet

Comment: gracias amigo lo solucione con la primera opción busque una clase que se direrenciaba de cada pagina y especificaba el elemento y colocaba la imagen me sirvio mucho muchas gracias